Is the new game Nine Sols actually a metroidvania?
According to the Wikipedia definition of a metroidvania, the genre is described as:

[...] a sub-genre of action-adventure games and/or platformers focused
on guided non-linearity and utility-gated exploration and progression.

I've seen footage of the demo, and a little bit of footage of the full game (which released around 12 hours ago). What I saw while watching seemed to be very "guided." It looked like there was only one path, one direction, that it forced you to take at all times (though bear in mind I haven't seen much footage). The direction switches, yes, but it still seemed very guided.

Are my first assumptions of the game correct? Does it open up more as you progress? If so, how much does it open up by? Does it open up by an amount similar to Hollow Knight, which gives a lot of freedom?

Also, I'd like to mention (because there was comment controversy) that from what gameplay I saw, there didn't seem to be anything that was blocked off from the player (unless it was going in a slightly different route, picking something up/killing something, and returning immediately).
It's also unlikely that there's anything blocked off with movement, as multiple movement abilities are immediately given to you.

I'm not sure "guidedness" is exactly the criteria I'd use to identify a Metroidvania -- after all, the eponymous "Super Metroid" spends the first 1/3 of the game running the player in a giant circle, only after which does the game world open up in full. I'd say the criteria for a metroidvania is much more about returning to previous areas with new abilities that lets you take paths that were previously unobtainable, rather than anything related to the critical path.

Same as Raven, for all metroids games I played (and what I remember for a few castlevania), Barring sequence skip (either legitimate through hard manipulations or through exploit), there is ONE sequence to finish the game. You need to explore and backtrack to find it (and by explore, I mean go to the blinking room on your map), but there is only an illusion of liberty, until end game.

@RavenDreamer I didn't see any places where things were locked from the player (more info in the updated question).

Yes
Long explanation below;
Unlike 'species classification' in biology, game genre classification is a bit more 'fuzzy'. For some genres, a pioneering game (examples: Metroid, Rogue, Command & Conquer, Civilization, Transport Tycoon) is wildly popular and future creators will look to it as inspiration and design new games that are refinements of this existing game (or, in the case of Rogue, applying its structure to another genre).
'2D Platformer' is a relatively solid genre definition. To be a 2D platformer, the game must have;

Gameplay is restricted to two dimensions at a time, Z and X.
The perspective is 'from the side'.
The player controls a single character at a time, that can move left and right.
The game has a jump button.
There are environmental hazards (moving platforms, spikes) that create consequences for failing. (A very tall tower would also work, as the consequence is being sent back to an earlier point in the game).

The fifth one here is the most fuzzy as it can be from very lenient to unfun levels of unforgiving. In general though, I wouldn't call a game a platformer if you couldn't in some way lose or suffer a setback for imprecise acrobatics.
For example, if the game fails criterion (3), it's usually called a side scroller rather than a platformer. Nine Sols definitely looks like a 2D platformer, as it meets all five of these requirements.
Ask two people about what a 'metroidvania' is, and you'll get different answers much more often. A conservative definition would be 'a 2D Platformer that is also sufficiently alike to Metroid or Castlevania'. Here's 10 elements of these games;

There is a fluid combat system, using hitboxes in the style of fighting games.
There are many 'hidden areas' to find.
The game is divided into multiple screens, tiled vertically or horizontally.
Enemies tend to take few hits to kill.
Enemies deal 'contact damage'.
Some enemies regenerate upon reloading a screen.
Additional abilities are unlocked during gameplay.
You return to areas you've been to before.
There are no 'points of no return' until the end sequence. That is: There are no 'levels', for there is one big map.
The game, at some point, features branching paths you can do in the order of your choice.

This isn't an exhaustive list. Nor would a game need every little detail to qualify (in that case, the game just is Castlevania, not 'a castlevania-like game').
Currently, on the Steam Store (2024-06-05) the game is labelled as a 'Metroidvania' with a user-defined tag. I don't currently have insight in how many users have voted to keep or remove this tag, or what the algorithm is for keeping vs. burninating tags on Steam. According to popular vote, Nine Sols is close enough to qualify.
